# Vue.js Compile Error: no-unused-vars & no-undef

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently trying to create a Vue.js component. When I start the app there's an error.
The error message as shown below:

[image]

```
<template>
    <div class="hello" id="app">
         <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="#">{{name1}}</a>
            <a href="#">{{name2}}</a>
            <a href="#">{{name3}}</a>
            <a href="#">{{name4}}</a>

            <div id="bottom">
                <input v-model="name1" style="margin-left: 25px;max-width: 50%;">
                <input v-model="name2" style="margin-left: 25px;max-width: 50%;">
                <input v-model="name3" style="margin-left: 25px;max-width: 50%;">
                <input v-model="name4" style="margin-left: 25px;max-width: 50%;">
            </div>

        </div>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elit velit, dictum in urna et,
            vulputate ornare sapien. Phasellus sed metus sed dolor hendrerit iaculis.
            Cras eget libero sit amet massa aliquet dignissim. Vivamus faucibus lorem sit amet semper luctus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In at placerat
            felis,
            id finibus mauris. Proin maximus orci quis lacus pellentesque, ac dignissim sapien vestibulum. Maecenas
            pharetra
            vulputate semper.
            Suspendisse potenti. Donec nisi nisi, aliquam eget felis euismod, semper dictum ligula.
            Aenean mauris enim, iaculis vel malesuada vel, pulvinar et risus. Fusce sit amet orci eget diam commodo
            ultricies sed vel elit.
            Curabitur quis scelerisque est.</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    //Vue App
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            /*
            navlink: [
                {id: 1, link: "https://www.tfbern.ch"}, 
                {id: 2, link: "https://www.tfbern.ch"},
                {id: 3, link: "https://www.tfbern.ch"},
                {id: 4, link: "https://www.tfbern.ch"}
                ]
            */

            name1: 'name 1',
            name2: 'name 2',
            name3: 'name 3',
            name4: 'name 4'
        }
    })
    export default {
        name: 'NavigationDrawer',
        props: {
            msg: String
        }
    }

    //Navbar Animation
   /* 
   function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0"; -->
    }
     */
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Navigation-Drawer.vue

---

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
    <App msg="test">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import App from './components/Navigation-Drawer.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    App
  }
}

</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

App.vue

Comment: Have you set up your app using `vue-cli` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to create a Vue instance using `new Vue` inside a `.vue` file. That belongs in `app.js` or `main.js` or whatever your main JS file is called.

Comment: @SatyamPathak yes

Comment: @skirtle What should I use instead of new Vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the errors from eslint. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars and https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef for details.

In order to remove these errors, add this line just before the line where you are initializing the app

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    var app = new Vue({ 
    // rest of the code
```

Make sure that the line with `eslint-disable-next-line` is commented. This will tell eslint to ignore that line and not lint it.

Comment: This removed the error but now the site is just blank.

Comment: Check your console for other errors. And please provide a jsfiddle or codepen with all related code.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. **What line exactly** do I need to add? You answer contains several lines, one of them initializing a Vue object which *I dont* do

Answer (score 0):

The CLI should have created a file called `main.js`. In there you'll have something a bit like this that creates a new Vue instance:

```js
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).mount('#app')
```

It might use an `el` property instead of calling `mount` and it may mention `store` or `router` if you chose to include those when creating the project. It doesn't really matter, the key thing is that this is where the root Vue instance gets created. Unless you're writing an atypical application you shouldn't need to use `new Vue` again. You certainly shouldn't be using it inside a `.vue` file.

The `App` referenced in the code I wrote above should be the component in `App.vue`, which should be imported earlier in `main.js`.

Then there's your `App.vue`. This line is a bit odd:

```js
import App from './components/Navigation-Drawer.vue'
```

Technically it isn't wrong but it's really confusing. Rename `App` to some a bit more sensible, like `NavigationDrawer`. You'll need to update everywhere it's used, including the template.

Next up, `Navigation-Drawer.vue`. There are several problems here.

Firstly, get rid of the `id="app"` on the template, that just shouldn't be there and may cause problems.

To implement `onclick="openNav()"` in Vue you'd instead write `@click="openNav"` and then define `openNav` within the `methods` section of the component.

The script section should look something like this:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'NavigationDrawer',

        props: {
            msg: String
        },

        // Note that this is a function when used on a component
        data () {
            return {
                name1: 'name 1',
                name2: 'name 2',
                name3: 'name 3',
                name4: 'name 4'
            }
        },

        methods: {
            openNav() {
                console.log('openNav called')
            },

            closeNav() {
                console.log('closeNav')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hopefully that'll be enough to get it all working.

The original linting errors were caused because:

1. You were creating a variable called `app` but never using it.
2. You were trying to call `new Vue` but hadn't imported `Vue`. In general you need to import things if you want to be able to access them from inside a `.vue` file.

However, the linting errors were just side-effects of the more serious problems I've outlined above.